# Scope of variables when calling function from find

Tags: bash, find, function, variable

In a bash script I define a function that is called from `find`. The problem is that the scope of variables does not extend to the function. How do I access variables from the function? Here is an example:

```
variable="Filename:"

myfunction() {
    echo $variable $1
}

export -f myfunction

find . -type f -exec bash -c 'myfunction "{}"' \;
```

This will output filenames but without the string "Filename:".

Is there perhaps a better way to invoke a function from `find` such that it is called for every file that `find` finds, and variables are still defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare `variable` as an environment variable, i.e.,

```
export variable="Filename:"
```

Answer (score 7):

Not an answer to your question, but do **not** do:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'myfunction "{}"' \;
```

Beside the fact that it's not portable, it's also very dangerous, because the file names end up being interpreted by `bash` as shell code. Consider for instance what would happen if there was a file called `$(rm -rf ~)` down there. Write it:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'myfunction "$1"' find+bash {} \;
```

Or even better (to avoid running one `bash` per file):

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'for file do
  myfunction "$file"; done' find+bash {} +
```

Now an answer to your question to be on topic:

You could do:

```
{ find . -type f -exec printf '%s\0' {} + | while IFS= read -ru3 -d '' file; do
  myfunction "$file"; done 3<&0 <&4 4<&-; } 4<&0
```

That way, you're calling `myfunction` within the current `bash` shell, so you don't need to export `myfunction` or run additional `bash` shells.

If your `find` supports the `-print0` predicate (like GNU, busybox and some BSDs `find`s), you can replace `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +` with `-print0`

Comment: Ah, I see. Note taken. I was guessing that my approach was not the best choice.

Comment: Great, thanks. I will look into your updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as follow

```
#!/bin/bash

myfunction() {
    local var="Filename: "
    local file=$1 
        echo "$var" "$file"
    }

export -f myfunction
    find . -type f -exec bash -c 'myfunction {}' \;
```

Declare vars as local and pass '{}' to the function which is `$1` first positional parameter.

Comment: The variable I want to use within the function (`var` in your example) is defined *outside* the function in my case.

Comment: Sure, You've defined a global variable but why since the `variable` is going to run/be part of the function itself.

Comment: Well, this was just an example. In my real script, the variable is used at many places, in particular outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign to a variable, it starts out as a shell variable. In order to get an environment variable that is passed to subprocesses, you need to export it.

```
variable="Filename:"
export variable
```

You can put the assignment on the same line as `export`: `export variable="Filename:"`.

The variable will be visible to the shells started by `find`, but not the functions. In bash, you can also export functions. This possibility is not present in ksh, dash and other shells that are often used as `sh` because they are faster and leaner.

```
export -f myfunction    # bash only
```

Never use `{}` inside a string in `find -exec …` (or `xargs …`), unless you know that your file names are alphanumeric. If there are any special characters in the file names, they will be parsed as such by the inner shell. Instead, pass the file names on the shell's command line.

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'for x; do myfunction "$x"; done' _ {} +
```

With shells other than bash, define the function in the inner shell, or just put its code directly.

Alternatively, in bash, you can use recursive globbing instead of find. Beware that bash traverses symbolic links to directories.

```
variable="Filename:"
myfunction () { … }
shopt -s globstar dotglob
for x in **/*; do
  if [[ -f $x ]]; then myfunction "$x"; fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. What initially confused me was that the variable was indeed accessible when calling the function on its own (not from `find`), e.g. having a line saying just `myfunction "hello.txt"`.